# jQuery sorttable doens't work after postback in updatepanel (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, updatepanel, jquery-ui-sortable, tablesorter

I have a issue with the sortable function of jQuery. When my page does a post-back with the update-panel the sorting of the dynamic table doesn't work anymore. The post-back is triggerd when a image-button is pushed. When the image-button is pushed there is a new row with a subtable in it.

I tried these 3 JavaScript codes but they all only seem to work for the first time. They DON'T work after I open the subtable.

Do you guys maybe know a JavaScript solution to solve this?

My first try:

```
$(function(){
        $('table[id*="tbl_main"]').tablesorter();
    });
```

My second try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('table[id*="tbl_main"]').tablesorter();
    });
```

My third try:

```
function pageLoad() {
        $(function () {
            $("#pager").unbind();
            $('table[id*="tbl_main"]')
            .tablesorter()
            .tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager") });
        }
    )}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After each update all scripts are removed, you have to bind them again like:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

     <ContentTemplate>
          <script type="text/javascript">
               Sys.Application.add_load(BindFunctions);
          </script>
...
```

And then in your javascript file:

```
function BindFunctions() {
$('table[id*="tbl_main"]').tablesorter();
};
```