# Jquery Chosen selected not working on asp listbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-chosen

I am using [Jquery Chosen Plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) on a listbox for multiple selection of items. But when I am retrieving the `selected` items, it does works, and the number of selected items remains 0.

This is how I am applying the control:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            $('#<%= this.listBox.ClientID%>').chosen();
        }
</script>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlAddUpdate" runat="server">
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpAddUpdate" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
     <asp:ListBox ID="listBox" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

This is my codebehind:

```
foreach (ListItem item in this.listBox)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
            list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(item.Value));
    }
```

The list remains empty..any idea what have I missed?

Comment: Hey, are you calling the function pageLoad,?

Comment: no. it is called when the page loads..

Comment: Do you really need here UpdatePanel?

Comment: I have other fields as well alongside the `listbox`, which work with updatepanel. Do you think it is the update panel that is causing this unexpected behavior?

Comment: Yes. After update of UpdatePanel your script is erased and no longer works.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497630/jquery-sorttable-doenst-work-after-postback-in-updatepanel-javascript

Comment: I got rid of the `updatepanel`, but still the issue persists..